# Send a public broadcast from an AppWidget in Android

Tags: android, widget, android-widget, broadcast

I have a widget for a music player and want to be able to send broadcasts when pushing the different buttons. What I want to do is when a button is pushed, the widget sends a public broadcast to another BroadcastReceiver so it can handle the different actions.

In my activity class with the BroadcastReceiver:

```
private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String action = intent.getAction();

    if (action.equals(Constants.ACTION_NEXT)) {
      Log.d("RECEIVER", "ACTION_NEXT");
    }
  }
};

@Override
protected void onStart() {
  super.onStart();
  IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();

  //Widget actions
  filter.addAction(Constants.ACTION_NEXT);

  registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(filter));
}
```

In my Widget:

```
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
  RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);

  PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, new Intent(Constants.ACTION_NEXT), 0);
  views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.WidgetNextButton, pendingIntent);
  appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
}
```

Any help or other solutions are very much appreciated!

EDIT: Forgot to mention my actual problem: The BroadcastReceiver never receive the broadcast

Comment: Ahhh, forgot to mention that.. The problem is that the BroadcastReceiver never receive the broadcast

Comment: Is your class "alive" to recieve the broadcast when its sent?

Comment: It's an Activity that is minimized at the moment, but it's alive I would guess. It's the main Activity for the music player... Any way to check if it's "alive"?

Comment: If its not in the foreground I dont think it will recieve the broadcast, try registering the broadcast in your activity in the manifest, that way the broadcast will be recieved even when your activity is in the background I believe

Comment: Hmmm... That would be problematic because I use an anonymous inner class. Unless it is possible to register that in the manifest somehow?