# Android : Receive custom broadcast when a button in a widget is clicked

Tags: android, android-widget, broadcastreceiver

I have a `BroadcastReceiver` that works fine, i.e. executing this code from an Activity, the receiver receives the intent:

```
Intent toggleIntent = new Intent(this, ToggleServicesReceiver.class);
this.sendBroadcast(toggleIntent);
```

But I am trying to do the same from a button in a Widget:

```
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {  
    ...
    Intent toggleIntent = new Intent(context, ToggleServicesReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, toggleIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    remoteView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_button, pendingIntent);
}
```

The code is called (I've checked it with the debugger), but when the user clicks the button, the same `BroadcastReceiver` does not receive the `Intent`.

What could be happening?

**Edit**: The `BroadcastReceiver` is defined in `AndroidManifest.xml`, and now I'm not sure if the `<intent-filter>` is needed:

```
<receiver android:name="foo.receivers.ToggleServicesReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="foo.intent.action.SERVICES_TOGGLE" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

**Edit**: I've also found this in a forum, it could be related with this problem

> You simply can not do this.  A
>   BroadcastReceiver component only
>   "lives" for the duration of the call
>   to onReceiveIntent(); it is not
>   allowed to use registerReceiver in it,
>   because by the time you return from
>   that method (at which point you could
>   first receive anything from your
>   register), the component is no longer
>   alive, and the system could kill at
>   any time to reclaim memory.

Comment: It sure looks good. Where is this `BroadcastReceiver` declared -- manifest or `registerReceiver()`? If the latter, are you sure it's actually registered at the time of the app widget click?

Comment: It is declared in the manifest, but I've tried it both ways.  I'm going to repeat my tests, just in case I missed something.  I've also found a close related question in SO with the same problem (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3044275/send-a-public-broadcast-from-an-appwidget-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

Consider this:

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, toggleIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
```